# Objective-C or ActionScript for iOS game development?

Tags: objective-c, flash, actionscript-3, actionscript, ios

As the title suggests, I'm interested in starting up iOS app development. I've used Java, PHP, Python and Javascript before, and have little experience in Actionscript or Objective-C. I've poked around with both, but not enough to know what would be better.

Since Adobe has a way to export SWF projects to the iOS platform, I was wondering if it would be wiser to learn Objective-C and use a framework such as [Sparrow](http://www.sparrow-framework.org/) or [Cocos2d](http://www.cocos2d-iphone.org/) to deal with the graphics and game portions, or, if it would be better to just learn Actionscript and develop the games in Flash, and then export them to .IPAs for the App Store.

Thanks in advance for the help! And I'm not trying to start a debate, just seeing if anyone out there has had the same decision as me and what their thoughts on it were.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Personally I think it's best to go straight to Objective-C and Cocos2d is a good framework, I used it myself.

I can't see a reason why you would choose to use AS3 if you want to develop for the iOS, but's that's just my personal opinion. And it's always a bit risky using 3rd parti API's ;)

Comment: Thanks, zebulon! I'll take your word for it, any sites/books you'd recommend to help get me started with Obj-C/Cocos2d?

Comment: Also from what I have heard, the conversion of AS3 to iPhone native code is not very optimized at present and only the simplest of games run at a decent framerate.

Comment: I'm a diehard flash guy so I wouldn't hesitate to recommend that to anyone, but with the performance issues and the reliance on third party tools I have a hard time recommending that. So I second the Objective C recommendation.

Comment: however, if you developed your mobile application in ActionScript 3.0 instead of Objective-C 2.0 you would have immediate access to nearly all other platforms, including the upcoming BlackBerry Playbook, as well as the currently unoptimized version for iOS.

Comment: @Parker, of course there are http://www.cocos2d-iphone.org/ . I recommend you to start reading "Learn Objective-C on the Mac" by Mark Dalrymple and Scott Knaster - publisher is Apress. That's great book to start with, be sure to get that under the christmas tree :)